# SSIS throw exception with destination SQL Server Destination

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, asp.net-core-2.0, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on data transfer using Visual Studio 2017; integration service; from SQL server table to another sql table in another database. Both have different database schema and not all data from source been tried to copy in destination.

Now I manage to copy all the data if 'Other Destination' is 'Flat File Destination'  but throw exception when destination is 'SQL Server Destination'. My another issue it doesn't show any problem on design page but error in debug screen but no really error message!!

### design page

[image]

### debugger page; where error throw but no detail about error?????????

[image]

### error

[image]

I am new to SSIS, not sure what I am missing;

Comment: Have you checked the Execution Results tab when the package is done running?

Comment: I cannot see Execution Results tab

Comment: Try checking the one that says "Progress" on the right in second screen-shot.

Comment: Yes I found and paste screen shot in above question

Comment: Are you running this as an admin?  i.e.right-click SSDT and select Run as Administrator?

Comment: could be this:  [google...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2009672/you-may-get-unable-to-prepare-the-ssis-bulk-insert-for-data-insertion)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UAC Enabled? In that case it might be the reason why you are facing this issue.

On systems where UAC(User account Control) is enabled, SSIS is uses a low priveleged token by default which causes it to fail when connecting to a SQL Destination.

If this is the case, you either need to start SSIS as an administrator or replace your SQL destination with an ole db destination